Google Analytics: doesn't log geo of users
Our team use Firebase for event analytics in mobile app. My goal right now - explore how people change themself geolocation in time (or sessions). I wrote sql-query in BigQuery and tried the logic of users. I have a huge amount anomalies rows, where you can think users teleport between far from each other countries.
For exapmle, Can you explain why is difference in several seconds and change location from UK to
islands of central Asia? How detect geolocation GA or Firebase system of users in raw data?
Main parts of query:
I.
WITH sessions_with_geo AS(
SELECT
    CAST(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AS DATE) as date,
    user_pseudo_id,
    geo.city,
    geo.country,
    TIMESTAMP_MICROS(MIN(event_timestamp)) as first_date,
    TIMESTAMP_MICROS(MAX(event_timestamp)) as last_date
FROM `XXXX.analytics_XXX.events_2024033*`
GROUP BY  1,2,3,4)

II.
location_moves AS (
SELECT
    date,
    user_pseudo_id,
    country,
    city,
    CASE 
        WHEN country  = LAG(country) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY date) THEN 'Not changed'
        WHEN LAG(country) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY date) IS NULL THEN 'Not changed'
        ELSE LAG(country) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY date)
    END AS prev_country,
        CASE 
        WHEN city  = LAG(city) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY date) THEN 'Not changed'
        WHEN LAG(city) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY date) IS NULL THEN 'Not changed'
        ELSE LAG(city) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY date)
    END AS prev_city,
    LAG(last_date) OVER(PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY date) AS prev_session_end,
    first_date,
    last_date
FROM sessions_with_geo

)
III.
SELECT
    *
FROM location_moves
WHERE user_pseudo_id in (SELECT user_pseudo_id FROM location_moves GROUP BY 1 HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN prev_country <> 'Not changed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)


In your first CTE you've prefixed city and country with the "geo" alias which suggests they are coming from a different table than the rest of your columns - but there is no such aliased table in your SQL. Please can you explain this (or explain how I've misunderstood your SQL)? Thanks

geo is "super" column that data type has name RECORD type,  u can read https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated, i hope my answer is useful)
